# Test an AWS lambda locally using custom container image

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I am trying to test the newly added [feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html) of running / invoking `lambda` with custom container image, so I am building a very simple image from `AWS` `python:3.8` base image as follows:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8


COPY myfunction.py ./

CMD ["myfunction.py"]
```

And here is `myfunction.py`

```py
import json
import sys

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Hello AWS!")
    print("event = {}".format(event))
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
    }
```

My question is the following: after my build is done:

```
docker build --tag custom .
```

how can I now invoke my lambda, given that I do not expose any web endpoints and assuming I am spinning up my custom container with success, (although the `handler=` part is a little bit unsettling in terms of whether I have configured the handler appropriately)

```
▶ docker run -p 9000:8080 -it custom
INFO[0000] exec '/var/runtime/bootstrap' (cwd=/var/task, handler=)
```

A simple curl of course fails

```
▶ curl -XGET http://localhost:9000                                                                                                                                                                       
404 page not found
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out I have to invoke this extremely non-intuitive url

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '{}'
```

However I am still getting this error

```
WARN[0149] Cannot list external agents                   error="open /opt/extensions: no such file or directory"
START RequestId: f681b2ca-5e35-499d-a262-dd7bc53912f0 Version: $LATEST
Traceback (most recent call last):andler 'py' missing on module 'myfunction'
END RequestId: f681b2ca-5e35-499d-a262-dd7bc53912f0
REPORT RequestId: f681b2ca-5e35-499d-a262-dd7bc53912f0  Init Duration: 1.08 ms  Duration: 248.05 ms     Billed Duration: 300 ms    Memory Size: 3008 MB    Max Memory Used: 3008 MB
```

**edit**: Solved by changing the `CMD` from

```
CMD ["myfunction.py"]
```

to

```
CMD ["myfunction.lambda_handler"]
```

Comment: Yeah that seems a bit funky, that date is littered all over the JS sdk, I reckon chuck that out in config on the off chance they change it.

Why not just use serverless locally(pip install gives the deps that'd be used in the image)?

Comment: Any relevant instructions about this process and the corresponding invocatio

Comment: Check this out, will add an answer shortly. https://www.serverless.com/blog/container-support-for-lambda/

Comment: You can then use the serverless offline plugin(I think) https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline - that'll give you local functions running your desired container NOTE: I need to check this when I get home.

Comment: Just figuring out of sls offline supports containers.., give me a short while.

Comment: Sure. seems your answer will be more convenient so I might as well accept it as the correct one